# Delete Old Workspaces on TFS VS2013

Tags: tfs, cmd

I am trying to map a folder structure on TFS to my C: drive, but I get this error [ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Vv8.png) saying the C:/DEV-MAIN folder is already in use by another workspace.

The workspace was created on this machine by the previous user who's windows login has been deleted. I can't access it from TFS directly because I don't have access to it.

Next, I tried to remove it from the command line using 'tf workspace /delete'. As show on this [CommandLineImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7zjQ.png) I found 2 workspaces on my machine (mine and the old one). Then, I tried to select just the workspaces owned by 'sjayasekar'. It said "The Identity sjayasekar is not a recognized identity", yet it clearly shows that she is the owner.

I also tried to delete it as show on the previous command line image, but it says that the workspace does not exist.

Any idea why it won't recognize the workspace or the owner when I try to reference them specifically? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I highly suggest picking up `Team Foundation Sidekicks 2013` for this. It makes workspace deletion among a lot of other things fairly trivial. I can't tell you how much time that tool has saved me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `tf workspace` command to delete other's old workspace.
Make sure you have own **manage other users workspace** permission. Otherwise, you need to get your TFS administrator to delete the workspace if you have no access to the account. Just using below command.

```
tf workspace /delete "WORKSPACENAME;PREVIOUSUSERACCOUNT"
```

If this is still not work, you can also try to use [**TFS Sidekick**](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/).
Then open workspace sidekick Search for the 'xx' user and then you can delete his workspace.
[image]

*Note: TF Sidekicks uses the same commands so would require the same permission. It is a TFS admin productivity tool.*

More detail steps please refer the *RezaRahmati's* answer in this question [how to remove TFS workspace mapping for another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298771/how-to-remove-tfs-workspace-mapping-for-another-user)

Comment: i am curious to know, how is the workspace sidekick is appearing in the visual studio. Sorry for asking a out of context question.

Comment: After install the tool .Then should be a new menu will  added to Visual Studio as below

`Menus -> Tools -> TeamFoundation Sidekick`

Comment: Eureka! TFS Sidekick worked great. Thanks for the tip.