# Visual studio alerts workspace already exists

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfs-2015

I am having an issue with one of the users of a TFS server I manage. We recently went through a user ID change and as such this messed up some of our workspaces. I am trying to get a new local workspace made on her machine and it keeps saying that the locally mapped folder is already used for her old workspace.

We have deleted all of the TFS and VS cache folders, did userdatareset, and using the tf.exe workspaces command it does not list this offending workspace that I am trying to get rid of. Is there other approaches I can use to get rid of this workspace.

Comment: What version of TFS and VS are you using? Also, under the "Manage Workspaces" window, have you checked the remote workspaces to see if the old workspace is still there?

Comment: @Toomaja This is using VS 2013 and TFS 2015. Under the manage workspaces folder checking remote workspaces did not show any additional workspaces unfortunately.

Comment: What's the detail workspace command are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the tf workspace command to delete other's old workspace. Make sure you have own **manage other users workspace permission**. Otherwise, you need to get your TFS administrator to delete the workspace if you have no access to the account. Just using below command.

```
tf workspace /delete "WORKSPACENAME;PREVIOUSUSERACCOUNT"
```

---

You could also use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), for TFS2015, it's version 6.0

**How to use the tool:**

- After download and install it, you need to connect to TFS
  server with your current authentication.
- Open tools- select workspace sidekick

[image]

- In the filters, select the **owner name**, **computer name**,
  **access date**

[image]

- Finally, you should be able to delete the abandoned workspace.

*Note: TF Sidekicks uses the same commands so **would require the same permission**. It is a TFS admin productivity tool.*

More details please refer the similar question: [Delete Old Workspaces on TFS VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982364/delete-old-workspaces-on-tfs-vs2013)

Comment: I ended up going with the command line route as the Sidekicks app didn't list everything even though I am an admin on the TFS server. Anyway, that got it working for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to view all workspaces for that particular machine and delete the ones you no longer need.

I use it to clean up workspaces for people that left the company and workspaces that people forgot they had on their old machines. In theory, you should be able to do everything with tf.exe, but using Team Foundation Sidekicks, just makes it a lot easier.