# solution with the same name does exist but it is not visible / Microsoft TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Not the first time adding a new solution to TFS. I am trying to add a new solution and it comes up with a window prompt  to change the path where I want it to be mapped due an existing folder with the same name, even though I physically can not see that particular folder?

Comment: Have you issue solved? There should be something long with your workspace. Did you give a try with my solution below?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I had to create a new workspace and delete the old one, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to **get latest** of your workspace. There maybe some files hadn't download to local yet.

If after it you still can't see that particular folder. This may caused by there is an abandon workspace exists a mapping relationship. You could either use `tf workspace` command or  [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to delete that annoying workspace. Detail steps please refer my reply in this link: [Visual studio alerts workspace already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704081/visual-studio-alerts-workspace-already-exists/41714455#41714455)

For more ways, you could also take a look at this similar question: [Team Build Error: The Path ... is already mapped to workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226288/team-build-error-the-path-is-already-mapped-to-workspace)