# Removing references from renamed VSTS project (not TFS)

Tags: azure-devops

I had deleted a project from VSTS and would like to use the same name again for my project but when I try to create the project, I get this error:

[image]

All of the desktops that this message is referring to are gone e.g. old employees, virtual desktops, etc.

How do I get past this error? I'd hate to retire a project name because of old desktops or ex-employees that will never access this project again.

UPDATE:

When you know what you're doing, everything is easy and questions like mine are frowned upon, so much so that someone suggested this post should be closed. Very nice!

So, I'm told both TFS and VSTS work the same way and I should go learn what I need to learn from the other post. According to the linked post, I need to go run `TF` command which according to the answers is located in `Visual Studio 20xx/Common7/IDE` folder. I go there and `TF.exe` is NOT there. I then start searching my computer to locate this executable and my computer can't find it. I then Google it and here's what I see on Microsoft's documentation. What gives?????

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove TFS workspace mapping for another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298771/how-to-remove-tfs-workspace-mapping-for-another-user)

Comment: That post is about TFS not VSTS.

Comment: That answer is applicable to VSTS and TFS. There's no difference between a TFVC workspace in on-prem TFS and a TFVC workspace in VSTS.

Comment: What is a collection on VSTS? Is it a project? When I log into VSTS, I only see projects, not collections.

Comment: VSTS has one collection per account. Your project collection is the URL to your VSTS account, like `https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but this is not a user-friendly experience by any stretch of the imagination. Admittedly, I'm not investing my time into learning some key concepts but in my defense I need to focus on my project. Clearly my approach is not working because I keep running into issues. But for the love of God, take a look at the update I just posted in my original post. Nothing about this is friendly at all.

Comment: What's the version of your VS? You can install Team explore or using TEE cli: https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2). I already have Team Explorer in Visual Studio and I'm already using it to check my code in/out of my VSTS repository. Is the Team Explorer you're referring to an additional tool?

Comment: Check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`

Comment: Yup! It's there and I was able to issue the `TF` commands. Thank you! Is there a way to remove these workspaces through the VSTS portal or is using the `TF` command the only way to handle this?

Comment: There isn't the way to remove workspaces through VSTS portal. You also can remove workspaces through Visual studio directly. (Manage workspaces and check Show remote workspaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding VS2017, the Tf.exe is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`, you also can call TF command in **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017**.

On the other hand, you also can remove workspaces through Visual Studio directly (Manage workspaces and  check Show remote workspaces option)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think it would be really useful if this could be done through the VSTS portal as well.