# Unlock TFS files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm using the TFS online and I checked out some source files but I have to format my PC and lost all the source workspace. These files remain checked out and I can't unlock this files.

Answer (score -3):

If you login into the source control with the admin account, you will be able to force undo checkout, or check in with any file you provide.

Just try below ways to unlock the file:

- `tf lock /lock: none` Please see [Lock Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/lock-command) for details:

> To use the lock command, you must have the Lock permission set to
>   Allow. Having the Unlock other user's changes permission set to Allow
>   is required to remove a lock held by another user if you do not have
>   Write permission for that user's workspace

`tf lock /lock:none /workspace:workspacename [/recursive][/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]`

- `tf undo` The undo command removes any locks on the items. See [Undo command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/undo-command)

  To unlock individual files run the command below in Visual Studio Command Prompt:

  `tf undo "file_path" /workspace:workspace_name`

  e.g.:

  `tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/Abc.dll /workspace:Houst01`

  here it will unlock Abc.dll which is inside abc folder.

  To unlock the whole folder in one shot:

  `tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/* /workspace:Houst01`

  here it will unlock all files which is inside abc folder.
- Force remove the workspace (See [Deleting a TFS workspace from the command line](http://myalmblog.com/2016/07/deleting-a-tfs-workspace-from-the-command-line/) for details.)
- You can also unlock other users file using [TFS Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) tools:

  It gives you a graphical interface to do all these commands, which makes it much easier to perform these tasks.

---

Other related threads:

- [How to unlock a file from someone else in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server)
- [how to remove TFS workspace mapping for another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298771/how-to-remove-tfs-workspace-mapping-for-another-user)