# How to manage workspaces of the entire team in Visual Studio Team Services Online?

Tags: azure-devops

We have this VSTS online account, and we want to see a list of all mapped workspaces of all users in one place.

We know that we can go to each developer's PC and use `tf.exe workspaces` to get the list of workspaces on that machine.

But we need to do it without going to each developer's PC. The reason we need this is that we suspect some team members use their credentials and map a workspace on a machine outside our company's environment, without our permission.

Is there a way to see all mapped workspaces in one central place?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: No, I still have this requirement and it's a must IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use something like [Attrice TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/). It should work with VSTS, even if it doesn't say it does.

However, the more permanent solution is to set up [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azure-portal) in your Azure AD. That allows you to add restrictions so that your users cannot log in from outside your network.

Comment: TFS Sidekick is obsolete as of TFS 2015. Do you know of such tool for Devops 2018?

Comment: @Christian As far as I know the latest released version still works again 2018 and beyond.

Comment: I just get some exception after a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

(I know it's an old post, but researching for my own purposes...)

Extrapolating off of [how to remove TFS workspace mapping for another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298771/how-to-remove-tfs-workspace-mapping-for-another-user)

The following worked for me:

```
>tf.exe workspaces /collection:https://contoso.visualstudio.com/ /owner:*
```